# Does handling player input on separate thread make sense?

Tags: libgdx

I was having problems using

```
Gdx.input.isTouched()
```

My game is like flappy bird, and I have a boolean called alreadTouched.

I use this method for player tap input:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
    alreadyTouched = true
}else{
    alreadyTouched = false;
}
```

The problem is that it only recognizing 99% of the touches. Occasionally it will miss a touch for some reason. Does it make any sense to put the controls on a separate thread?

Comment: If you add the code where you use "alreadyTouched" we can help you find the real problem.

Comment: I find that using an InputProcessor is much easier and less error prone than trying to juggle booleans and calls to the various isTouched, justTouched, etc. methods.

Comment: I implemented inputprocessor and used an input multiplexer. The odd thing is that the same thing ocurrs, but only when using the multiplexer

Answer (score 0):

No. It does not make sense. Not in your case. For a simple game like Flappy Bird, or most games really, input on a separate thread does not make sense.

Your problem with an occasional missing touch input will not be solved by adding threading. The problem is either your physical device or your code.

If you were to handle input in a new thread, you would check for input, then you would have to wait for synchronization on the main thread to handle the input anyway.
Threading is for heavy computation like physics calculation/simulation that you want to handle in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an InputHandler if you're using Scene2D. (Which you should, tbh)

Have a look at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling .